# Cannot access nvidia-settings after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, settings

I have just upgraded to 13.10 from 13.04 and I am having hard time finding `nvidia-settings` to access it. After performing `updatedb` I can see it in the `PATH` but it is a `dead symlink`

```
$ ll /usr/bin/nvidia-settings
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Apr 10  2013 /usr/bin/nvidia-settings -> /etc/alternatives/nvidia_settings
$ ll /etc/alternatives/nvidia_settings
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 56 Apr 10  2013 /etc/alternatives/nvidia_settings -> /usr/lib/nvidia-settings-304-updates/bin/nvidia-settings
$ ll /usr/lib/nvidia-settings-304-updates/bin/nvidia-settings
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/nvidia-settings-304-updates/bin/nvidia-settings: No such file or directory


$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia-settings
rc  nvidia-settings                           295.33-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Tool of configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
rc  nvidia-settings-304-updates               304.88-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-settings-319-updates               319.60-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
rc  nvidia-settings-experimental-310          310.14-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
rc  nvidia-settings-updates                   304.51-0ubuntu2                            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia.*319
ii  nvidia-310-updates                        319.60-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-310-updates
ii  nvidia-319-updates                        319.60-0ubuntu1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii  nvidia-settings-319-updates               319.60-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done to fix it is:

Launch `Software & Updates`, go to `Additional Software` tab and mark `nvidia-319` (the stable version not the updates one) and that worked.

[image]